# kendo-multiselect with k-rebind model and options

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, angular-directive

Can we rebind model and options using k-rebind in kendo-multiselect angular directive.

```html
<select id="{{ vm.id }}" 
 class="k-textbox InputBox inputBoxText"
 kendo-multiselect
 ng-disabled="vm.ngDisabled"
 k-ng-model="vm.ngModel" 
 k-options="vm.options"
 k-rebind="vm.options">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer..

```html
var kendoMultiSelect = $("#"+vm.id).find('select').data("kendoMultiSelect");
    kendoMultiSelect.dataSource.options = vm.options;
    kendoMultiSelect.dataSource.options.value = vm.ngModel;
```